# My javascript is only working on 1st variation attribute and not on all

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is my javascript code which I have written in functions.php and this code is working perfect but only on 1st variation. I have tried this to open 2nd variation first after reload but it didn't work. It is working on every first variation of every product. Kindly help me out with this code.

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'script');
function script()
{
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            jQuery('#woocommerce-product-data').on('woocommerce_variations_loaded', function () {
                jQuery(this).find('.woocommerce_variation').each(function () {
                    jQuery("#dp").keydown(function () {
                        var cost = document.getElementById("cost").value;
                        var dp = document.getElementById("dp").value;
                        console.log(dp);
                    });
                });
            });
        });

    </script>


    <?php

}
```

Comment: "woocommerce_variation" Is this your custom field Upon Product Variation Selection?

Comment: no woocommerce_variation is a function. My custom field is #dp

Comment: Is there _one_ `#dp` and `#cost` each on the page in question - or are there more than one of either? (Duplicate IDs are not allowed in HTML.)

Comment: You can also do that through a template override of woocommerce for the custom fields.

Comment: Let me clear this out. My main question is that my keydown function is only working on first variation. I want it to work on aall the variations. I think issue in these lines jQuery('#woocommerce-product-data').on('woocommerce_variations_loaded', function () {
                jQuery(this).find('.woocommerce_variation').each(function () {